# A better way to mark a line, that will never be reached?

Tags: java, assertion, dead-code

Assuming this code snippet:

```
  public synchronized void kill() {
    log.info("Killing {}...", this);
    Runtime.getRuntime().halt(HALT_STATUS_CODE);
    assert false; // Line should never reach this point!
  }
```

Since the assert depends whether or not assertions argument is enable. Is there a better way to mark and check a line, that will never be reached at the execution time? (not only for this snippet)

Assertion doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html

Comment: `throw new RuntimeException("this is not even possible!");` - Although I don't really see the point in marking this line apart from the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace it with an IllegalStateException, replace

```
assert false;
```

with

```
throw new IllegalStateException("JVM is still running after calling halt");
```

Comment: Or it may be an `AssertionError` as well.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov no, `AssertionError` should not be used for such purpose.

Comment: Why not? It's literally the thing which is produced by failed `assert` statement.

Comment: Because of what you have written. This exception is internally used by `assert` so your code throwing an exception should not try to mimic an `assert`.

Comment: Because of the same reasons your code should not be throwing `OutOfMemoryError` or `StackOverflowError`, despite it can.

Comment: Both `OutOfMemory` and `StackOverflow` are `VirtualMathineError`s, while `AssertionError` is just a plain `Error` descendant. I feel there's quite a deal of difference between these two. Also, keeping VM running even after `Halt` command can be a candidate for `VirtualMachineError` itself, because it's clearly an error in virtual machine.

Comment: Another argument is that errors should not be thrown and unchecked exception should be used instead.

Comment: Again, why shouldn't they be thrown? Errors as a concept in Java are meant to represent exceptional conditions so bad they should never be recovered from. So by design, an Error should not be _caught_, but it doesn't mean it cannot be thrown.

Comment: I agree with @MProkhorov, marking a supposed-to-be-unreachable code location with `throw new AssertionError(…)` is perfectly matching the intent of `AssertionError`. The fact that `assert` statements use the same error doesn’t imply that the error is exclusively reserved for that; the `for` loop uses `Iterator` behind the scene, does that imply that we are not allowed to use `Iterator`s? Besides, there are already over hundred `throw new AssertionError(…)` statements in the `java.base` jdk code, so the jdk developer do not seem to agree that this is something to avoid…

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a `RuntimeException`.